# BigCommerce App Flow - BC to my service and vise versa

Tags: bigcommerce

I am trying to clarify I understand the flow of BigCommerce authentication. This is what I understand I need to build:

BigCommerce to my service:
1.User clicks to install my app. 
2. He approves the OAuth access to his account and then BigCommerce redirects to my app's callback URL. 
3. My app should take in token and store credentials and assign it to a user in my system. 
4. User is redirected to an installation page hosted on my end and I instruct him to install.

How does the other way around work? If user is exposed to the ability to use my service on BigCommerce on my website? Can I invoke the BigCommerce Oauth and operate the same as the process described above?

Moreover, is the process above correct?